# While Click at. Can't get the process "X"

Tags: applescript

The intention is to perform a single click at (x, y). I did try this method found on internet.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "X"
        click at {350, 50}
    end tell
end tell
```

And get an error ***System Events got an error: Can’t get process "X".***
After I did carefully look up in the AppleScript dictionary and found that it's a *responsibility* of `Process Suite` and gave it another shot, but still get the same error.


Can you please suggest what has been done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"X" would be the process that you want to perform the click (ex. Safari, Finder, etc). I've found that it can also be omitted.

```
tell application "System Events"
    click at {0, 0}
end tell
```

This should activate the Apple menu in the top left. You can use the crosshairs from the screenshot tool (⌘ + ⌃ + ⇧ + 4) to determine coordinates of objects on your screen. If the application needs to be active beforehand you can do something like

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        activate
        click at {20, 40}
    end tell
end tell
```